# understanding REST Response and HTTP status code

Tags: json, http, rest, http-status-codes

I wanted to know how I should respond in my REST API.

Valid Example:

```
http://blah.com/api/v1/dosomething/123
```

The above is a valid request and currently I have a HTTP Status of 200 with a JSON response

```
{
    "dosomething": {
        "status": "OK",
        "results": "123"
    }
}
```

Now my question is, if the parameter passed is not valid ( I'm expecting a string of whole numbers ), do I return a HTTP Response of 200 and pass the error status back in the JSON response or should I pass something like a HTTP 400 response ( Bad request ) and list the error / issue with the request in the JSON response?

Error Example:

```
http://blah.com/api/v1/dosomething/123a
```

JSON Response:

```
{
    "dosomething": {
        "status": "ERROR",
        "errors": [
            "Value passed: |123a| must be a integer."
        ]
    }
}
```

Again my question is should I pass a 200 or 400 HTTP status on the request where the parameter passed is not what I'm expecting? Or should this always be a 200 response as the request is working?

What is considered best practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use 404. Always. 404. To do otherwise is to misunderstand the nature of a URI and a resource. If `http://blah.com/api/v1/dosomething/` identified the resource, and `123a` were merely a parameter to it, then other codes could make sense. But it doesn't: `http://blah.com/api/v1/dosomething/123` identifies the resource. If no such resource exists, return `404 Not Found`.

You might possess some implementation detail that *handles* both resources `http://blah.com/api/v1/dosomething/123` and `http://blah.com/api/v1/dosomething/123a`, but it is not the resource. From Roy Fielding's [dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_2_3):

> "The resource is not the storage object. The resource is not a
>   mechanism that the server uses to handle the storage object. The
>   resource is a conceptual mapping -- the server receives the identifier
>   (which identifies the mapping) and applies it to its current mapping
>   implementation (usually a combination of collection-specific deep tree
>   traversal and/or hash tables) to find the currently responsible
>   handler implementation and the handler implementation then selects the
>   appropriate action+response based on the request content. All of these
>   implementation-specific issues are hidden behind the Web interface;
>   their nature cannot be assumed by a client that only has access
>   through the Web interface."

Comment: What if it's the wrong domain (eg I use the qual server on prod accidentally)? or api/v2/dosomething/123? or api/v1/dosomethingwrong/123? Or it's a 404 on an api gateway/CDN thats misconfigured and didn't forward the request to the origin? Or a bad DNS record that points to the wrong host? Returning 404 from the actual application code makes all of these an absolute PITA to tease out. Not that I disagree that this is the right "REST" answer, just that error handling in REST is a layering violation.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit by author: 422 is a wrong answer. I misunderstood initial question and gave invalid answer. Please see response by @fumanchu: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10955717/441250.** My answer below is wrong.

I'd suggest to use "422 Unprocessable Entity" and include failure information in the body of your response.

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
>   understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
>   415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
>   syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
>   status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained 
>   instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
>   request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
>   semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

It's unacceptable to use "200 Ok" or any other status codes when dealing with errors.

P.S.
List of status codes: 
http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml

Comment: So there is a correct HTTP Status to respond with. Does it matter if I'm using 1.0 or 1.1 HTTP Protocol Version?

Comment: Phil: it does not matter, but then -- in this case -- 422 is not the right response at all. For starters, there's no payload (request entity) in this request.

(422 is the right response in may other cases though)

Comment: @Julian you are absolutely right, i misunderstood initial question . Phill 422 is not right status code to use, i assumed that you are performing write operation.

Comment: Upvoting your answer as well as it contains useful information should someone come here with a question similar, but not quite the same. Also, as you updated it to point out that it is the wrong answer for the question; well, good on you. :)

Answer (score -2):

HTTP 400 is used to signify a problem with the HTTP request itself (such as an invalid HTTP header). Although you are not receiving the parameters you expect, the request is still a valid HTTP request, so I would return a 200 response but include details of the missing parameter in your JSON.

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding.  400 is an client application error so it could represent a whole range of failure cases.  The latest Httpbis spec changed the wording of the 400 error to show it can be applied more widely http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-19#section-7.4.1