# HTTP status code in REST API for using GET to query a “Not Ready Yet, Try Again Later” resource?

Tags: rest, http-get

First of all, I've read some relevant posts:

- [Best HTTP status code in REST API for “Not Ready Yet, Try Again Later”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794696/best-http-status-code-in-rest-api-for-not-ready-yet-try-again-later) It is about GET an item
- [Is it wrong to return 202 “Accepted” in response to HTTP GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099869/is-it-wrong-to-return-202-accepted-in-response-to-http-get) It is about GET an item
- [HTTP Status Code for Resource not yet available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080197/http-status-code-for-resource-not-yet-available) It is about POST
- [HTTP status code for in progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653850/http-status-code-for-in-progress) It is about GET but no clear answer.

but I still think I should raise my question and my thoughts here. What should be the HTTP status code in REST API for using GET to QUERY a “Not Ready Yet, Try Again Later” resource? For example, client tries to query all local news happen in future(!) by make an HTTP GET to this url: http://example.com/news?city=chicago&date=2099-12-31 so what shall the server reply?

These are the http status code I considered, their rfc definition and why I am not fully satisfied with:

- 3xx Redirection. **Comment**: Not an option because there is no other link to be redirected to.
- 503 Service Unavailable: The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a Retry-After header. **Comment**: The retry behavior is desired, but semantically the situation is not server's fault at all, so all 5xx look weird.
- 4xx Client Error. **Comment**: Looks promising. See below.
- 413 Request Entity Too Large: The server is refusing to process a request because the request entity is larger than the server is willing or able to process. ... If the condition is temporary, the server SHOULD include a Retry- After header field to indicate that it is temporary and after what time the client MAY try again. **Comment**: The retry behavior is desired, however the "Entity Too Large" part is somewhat misleading.
- 417 Expectation Failed: The expectation given in an Expect request-header field (see section 14.20) could not be met by this server. **Comment**: So it should be caused by an Expect request-header, not applicable to my case.
- 406 Not Acceptable: The resource ... not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request. **Comment**: so it is caused by the Accept request-header, not applicable to my case.
- 409 Conflict: The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. ... Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request. **Comment**: This one is close. Although my case is not about PUT, and isn't actually caused by conflict.
- 404 Not Found: The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. **Comment**: Technically, my url path (http://example.com/news) DOES exist, it is the parameters causing problems. In this case, returning an empty collection instead of a 404, is probably more appropriate.
- 403 Forbidden: The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. **Comment**: Generally this is supposed to be used in any restricted resource?
- 400 Bad Request: The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications. **Comment**: It is not true in my case. My server understands the request, its syntax is good, only the meaning is bad.
- 2xx Successful. **Comment**: If 4xx doesn't work, how about 2xx? See below.
- 200 OK. **Comment**: Fine. So what should I include in the response body? null or [] or {} or {"date": "2099-12-31", "content_list": null} or ... which one is more intuitive? On the other hand, I prefer a way to clearly differentiate the minor "future news" error from the more common "all query criteria are good, just no news this day" situation.
- 202 Accepted: The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon. **Comment**: Providing that we can use 202 in a GET request, it is acceptable. Then refer to the 200 comment.
- 204 No Content: The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body. **Comment**: Providing that we can use 204 in a GET request, it is acceptable. Just don't know whether this is better than 202 or 200.
- More on 2xx: **Comment**: I assume all 2xx response will likely be cached somewhere. But in my case, if I return an empty body for "tomorrow's news", I don't want it to be cached. Ok, explicitly specify the "no cache" headers should help.

Your thoughts?

Comment: Well, it is a matter of personal opinion in the end. Think I would prefer 200 OK with whatever body template you have chosen with an empty news entry, as there of course are no news to retrieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are retrieving the news for that day, which is a valid day, there just isn't any news. A 200 response of an empty body, or a what ever makes sense based on the mediatype would seem the logical. This depends on the media type you have decided with the client.

404 would make more sense if the date format was wrong (you asked for the 45th day of November, or asked for a city that doesn't exist.)

As an aside the URL would be better in the format http://example.com/news/chicago/2099-12-31 since that is the specific resource you want to retrieve. This format would make things like 404s clearer as well.

Comment: Ok, I want to differentiate 3 circumstances: a resource with some content, a resource with empty content, a resource doesn't exist at all. And I can see how your path-only url style perfectly maps them into: 200 with content, 200 with empty content (or perhaps a 204), and 404 not found. But now what if the url has to contain query string, like in my example? I just don't think all complicated query criteria can be arranged into path-only style.

Comment: If you have to use a sort of super resource that can be very different depending on query string I would stick with 200. How you convey no-news-yet or something along those lines is an issue outside of HTTP. It really depends on the media you are turning and what the client expects. For example in HTML you might simply say "No news yet", which a reader would understanding. But that is still content obviously since it is a HTML page. I wouldn't use 404 for a resource that exists but has changing content even if one version of that content could be no news.

Comment: "Super resource" is sometimes a natural choice if the service is kind of a search engine. 200 has a good point here. For example, do people or (author of) a program expect a sudden 404 when using google? Wouldn't that cause they think "did I just type a wrong host name or something"? And I like your saying **"I wouldn't use 404 for a resource that exists but has changing content even if one version of that content could be no content"**.

Comment: Yeah I think the search engine analogy is good. I would agree with what fumanchu says below about 404 if the resource itself doesn't exist, but ultimately it comes down to a meta discussion about what the resource is. Does the resource not exist, or is the resource "no news yet", which does exist. In the context of what you are describing I would go with a Resource that is "No news yet", in the same way that searching Google for something that doesn't exist still returns a search resource that just says zero results. "No news yet" is still a resource if that makes more sense to the client.

Comment: Or to put it another way, the "resource" is a news search query result. That resource always exists, even if it returns a search result with no news found.

Answer (score 4):

Use 404.

Your objection to it is based on a popular understanding of a URI as not including the querystring. "Because I have multiple URI's that map to the same handler," goes the logic, "my resource does in fact exist and is just being parameterized by querystring args."

This is incorrect. As [the URI spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) itself says in Section 3.3 (emphasis mine),

> "The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical
> form, that, **along with data in the non-hierarchical query
> component** (Section 3.4), serves to identify a resource within the
> scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority (if any)."

Resources are identified by URI's, and any change to any part of an absolute-URI identifies a separate resource. Tweet that to everyone you know once a day until they tell you to stop. Therefore a [404](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-24#section-6.5.4) is a perfect match: "The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a *current* representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Comment: I consider the main idea of your post is about "Resources are identified by the full URI, including the query string". Interesting, but is it a (de facto?) standard, and can you share some document on that? Regarding the "404" part, maybe it is subjective, and depend on the semantics: is news at 2099-12-31 an empty collection, or an non-existing collection. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Document shared. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10955717/23692 where various REST luminaries weigh in.

Comment: Thx @fumanchu. Firstly, if that "standard document" you shared is those quote from Roy's dissertation, I read it as describing the (no direct) relation between "resource in url" and "storage object in implementation". But then I realize you already gave the standard URI spec in your answer, so now I am ok with the "resources are identified by the full URI, including the query string" statement. So this is my **latest understanding: all problematic query string IN HTTP GET will (or must?) result in 404. Also applies to HTTP DELETE. But if this happens in HTTP POST or PUT, 400 is more usual.**